# Move (mv) file that starts with a hyphen (-)

Tags: linux, filenames, mv, move

I have a file called `-my-file-name.txt`. I'm trying to move it using the `mv` command, however it fails because the hyphen in the name is acting like an option.

```
mv -my-file-name.txt /some/new/folder
```

> mv: invalid option -- 'm'
>
> try 'mv --help' for more information.

How can I work around this?

I've tried the obvious, wrapping in single quotes (''), double quotes ("") and square brackets ([]), but none of these work.

Comment: The duplicate question concerns `rm`, but the solution is the same for `mv`, use `mv -- -my-file-name.txt /some/new/folder` or `mv ./-my-file-name.txt /some/new/folder`.

Comment: Thank you! This wasnt obvious from the `--help` options